# How to deploy a Pyramid app to DotCloud?

Tags: python, postgresql, pyramid, dotcloud

I have a Pyramid webapp with a Postgres database, and I'm using git for version control.

This is how my files are structured:

```
myapp/
  |----dotcloud.yml
  |----env/ # virtualenv
  |----MyProject/
        |
        |----production.ini
        |----requirements.txt
        |----myapp.sql
        |----myapp.psql
        |----wsgi.py
        |----myproject
              |
              |----scripts/
              |----static/
              |----templates/
              |----__init__.py
              |----views.py
              |----models.py
```

This is my dotcloud.yml:

```
www:
  type: python
  config:
    python_version: v2.7
  approot: home/home/myapp

db:
  type: postgresql
```

This is my `wsgi.py`:

```
from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging
ini.ath = '.../myproject/production.ini'
setup_logging(ini_path)
application = get_app(ini_path, 'main')
```

This is my (simplified) `__init__.py`:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
  engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
  DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
  config = Configurator(...)
  config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
  config.add_route('index', '/')
  # other routes...
  config.scan()
  return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

I've read the [official documentation](http://docs.dotcloud.com/) and the [third-party documentation](http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deployment/dotcloud.html) to get to this point but there must be something I'm not doing right. It's my first time deploying a webapp, and running my app locally still works.

In MyProject/ (where the `dotcloud.yml` file resides) I did `dotcloud create mydomainname`, `dotcloud connect mydomainname` and then `dotcloud push`. But I'm getting an internal server error. What am I doing wrong?

Also, the documentation says that if I'm using git, I must state that explicitly when I use `dotcloud create` or `dotcloud connect`, but what is the exact command?

EDIT: Before moving to DotCloud, I tried to use DigitalOcean, and had some problems when using pip to install the dependencies in requirements.txt. I had to do a git clone separately on the CLI so that I could enter my username and password, and I also had to install psycopg2 manually. Could this be one of the problems here too? If so, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you should try changing. First, do not push your virtualenv directory (`env`). The dotCloud builder will create another virtualenv based on your `requirements.txt`. One way to avoid pushing your *env* directory would be to move `dotcloud.yml` to `MyProject`. You seem to think that is where it is (*"In MyProject/ (where the dotcloud.yml file resides)"* ) but that is not what your file tree says.

Then, do the `dotcloud connect` or `dotcloud create` in `MyProject`, as you stated.

You should remove the `approot` line from your dotcloud.yml. Allow `approot` to go to its default, the current directory.